Deleted opinion based question on Bricks SE
Some time ago I've asked quite opinion based question on Bricks SE about emulation environment. I know that on the site it is ok to ask opinion based questions like this or this. My question was downvoted for unknown (for me) reason and after some time it was deleted. I flagged it and asked for undeletion because now I have an answer to my own question. I know that my question could be helpful for some people but I don't know what to do now. I have read the meta SE question about undeleting so I did the same but my question still deleted. Should I give up, create a new question and answer to it or just continue waiting for a moderator that hopefully will see my request?

This question was automatically deleted because it was 30 days old, voted to -1, and had no answers. I'll reverse that deletion so that you can add a constructive self-answer.

The author has now posted their self-answer, and it's substantive.
